# Premium to price ratio - Seemingly simple option research not so much

Tags: call-options

I would like to identify call options with weekly expiration dates that pay  the most premiums relative to the underlying stock price.

For example:

- As of 11/12/2019, TSLA has a price of ~350 per share.
- The $350 call expiring on 11/22/2019 has roughly $10 of premium.

Therefore, that's a 35:1 price to premium ratio.

Any recommendations on how I can research options like this? I am struggling with screeners on E*Trade and Yahoo without success.

Answer (score 1):

Because your  question isn't strategy specific, it leaves a bit  to interpretation.

If you want the most premium relative to the underlying stock price, pick the deepest in-the-money strike.  For example, the 11/22 $135 call is $216.  At $350, that's a huge ratio.  That's a near 100 delta call and if buying, you could achieve the same with a strike closer to $300.

But my guess is that you're after the maximum amount of time premium for selling and for that, you'd just look at  the at-the-money options because that's where  the maximum amount of time premium is found.

Unfortunately, few  stocks are exactly at a strike price so you'd have to look at the option with a strike price on either side of the stock's price.  Most of the time the highest time premium will occur at  the closest strike price unless the strike prices are wide.  So if you're looking at both strikes, you're going to have to factor out the ITM amount to determine the time premium.

For greater depth, you could   determine the time premium per day and divide by cost of acquisition (strike + premium).   if  looking at different expirations, determine premium per day and annualize the numbers to compare them on equal footing.

Your numerical  analysis will depend on what your strategy is.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio you are interested in is closely related to implied volatility (IV). The price to (at-the-money) premium ratio is approximately 251*sqrt(365/T)/IV, where T is days to expiration and IV is in percent. Thus, "the most premiums relative to the underlying stock price" will correspond to the highest IV.

Comment: That's a clever approach with minimal effort.  +1.  Download the average current IV for the universe of options and Excel an answer.